# optmizing inner join of two table with million of rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

SO I have two tables - reports (~30million rows) and reportsresponse (~333million row).

I am trying to join this

```
SELECT
  rr.ReportsResponseId,
  rr.Text,
  rr.type
FROM
  Reports r
  JOIN ReportsResponses rr
    ON rr.ReportId = r.Id
 WHERE
  r.UserId = 7077368;
```

This returns around (~25k) result which is not a lot, but still takes more than 10 second the execute.
I tried using indexes on all the Ids (userid, ReportId, ReportsResponseId), but the query still is pretty slow.

What else can I do to improve the performance of this?

using explain uses key for both

Comment: this is much faster when I run the query again, but that is presumably due to caching

Comment: Please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE Reports \G`

Comment: Add index `ReportsResponses (ReportId)`. Test indices `Reports (userid, id)` and `Reports (id, userid)`. *takes more than 10 second the execute* Are you sure that this is execution time? Maybe this is a time which needed for to transfer yuour 25 rows to your client?

Comment: As well as the `CREATEs`, please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'Reports%';`